# Getting data from Android device in laravel

Tags: json, laravel, getjson

I am trying to get data from android in server in laravel. What I did till now is :
here in my route:

```
    Route::any('jsondata','JsonController@jsonFunction');
```

And in my controller:

```
      public function jsonFunction()
 {
    $jsonPostedData = Input::all();
    return response(['jsonobjtest'=>$jsonPostedData]);
}
```

}

What it gives in browser is:

```
    {"jsonobjtest":[]}
```

Actually i want to do is i want to send a success message to android device when it sends data. And get data here in server.

Comment: Code seems correct. If you are calling it from the browser, what are the input params? Are you passing params via query string ?

Comment: @Deepak Thomas I am just doing this in browser: http://rentma.net/attendance/public/jsontest . I have no idea about passing the parameters.

Comment: It is working. http://rentma.net/attendance/public/jsontest?param1=yes 
Vikas' answer will be enough for you. When the android device sends data (by a POST call), this code will work. You are doing a test with GET, without params

Comment: @Deepak Thomas : Thank you. So what i need to do is now get the data from android right ? And Can i save the data that i get from android device in database? If yes can you hint me please.

Comment: @Deepak Thomas: now we have sent data from android. but how can i get that in browser?

Comment: @Deepak Thomas : I have to manually post data from browsers url. But i want to get those data sent from mobile devices. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm sorry to be blunt, but you are asking very basic things, both in code and in concept too. I would recommend you learn the basics by tutorials and trial and error. StackOverflow would not be the right place to learn basics and concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this

In your Controller

```
public function jsonFunction()
{
  $jsonPostedData = Input::all();

   // do something with your data insert or update or anything 

  if(count($jsonPostedData) > 0) // here you might write any of your condition.
  {
    return response()->json(['success'=>true]);
  }
  return response()->json(['success'=>false,'error'=>'your error message']);
}
```

Comment: thank you. Can you please tell me will this code work if data is sent from android device using the key "jsonobjtest" defined in my code?

Comment: Ya. it will work if you are making correct Api call. for ex: if you make a get or post request on the url `https://your domain.com/jsondata` and hitting this function you can do `Log::info('api call from andriod');` in your function and check `laravel.log` file if this message is comming or not.

Comment: where exactly i need to write that Log::info('api call from android'). And what do you mean when you said to check on laravel.log ? Can you please describe it.

Comment: within your controller's function at start you can write. which is related to your route. It is just for checking whether your Api call hitting the write function or not

Comment: But i need to manually provide data in browser. I am asking how can i get data from android mobiles when they send data to the server?

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code

```
  public function jsonFunction(){
    $requestObj=Input::all();
return response()->json(['success'=>true,'request_param'=>$requestObj]);
    }
```

Comment: when i did as you suggested and hit
 URL: http://rentma.net/attendance/public/jsontest it came {"success":true,"request_param":[]} and when i did the Post request from postman in this URL using 'request_param' as key and value="somevalue". It threw a bunch of HTML and CSS file

Comment: I have checked It's working for me. got you issue.

please open your kernel.php file and hide following line

// 'csrf' => \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class

and try it again

or either you need to set the header CSRF token

Comment: yeah it worked. But what can i do when i need to verifyCsrfToken. Why i needed to comment that line actually?

Comment: {
  "success": true,
  "request_param": {
    "request_param": "somedata"
  }
}
I got this above shown data . Actually i wanted to show that success/failure messege only to android device. And another thing is how can i save the data i get from android in my database. Can you please say me that?

Comment: It's laravel middle ware by default. you must have to passed token when you call post/put/delete request in header for security purpose. I suggest you that You need to passed CSRF token to achieve this action

Comment: And that success message should come only when the data came from device to server . But in postman it is coming even if i don't put that key and value in it. can we do sth there?

Comment: for that you have to written code for input validation like following

$rules = array(        
            'firstname' => 'required',
        );
 $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

 if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(array('status'=>0,'error'=>$validator->errors()->first();),200);
        } else {
            // DO YOUR CODE
   }

Comment: but theres no firstname thing

Comment: I have just given example.. It might be anthing or static ?

Comment: Ah Ah okay bro thank you so much. But can you please tell me how to save data i get in that request_param in database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138094/discussion-between-suz-aann-shrestha-and-hitesh-tank).

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether

`$jsonPostedData = Input::all();`

input contain data or not  by by simply

die and dumping  `$jsonPostedData` variable

example 
`dd($jsonPostedData);`